# Why do I receive two events after a update on dynamodb?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have configured dynamodb stream to trigger my lambda. When I update an item on dynamodb table, I see my lambda is triggered twice with two different event. The `NewImage` and `OldImage` are same in these two events. They are only different in `eventID`, `ApproximateCreationDateTime`, `SequenceNumber` etc.

And there is only 1 million second different based on the timestamp.

I updated the item via dynamodb console which means there should be only one action happened. Otherwise, it is impossible to update item twice within 1 million second via console.

Is it expected to see two events?

Answer (score 0):

This would not be expected behaviour.

If you're seeing 2 separate events this would indicate 2 separate actions occurred. As theres a different time this indicates a secondary action has occurred.

From the [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) the following is true

> DynamoDB Streams helps ensure the following:
>
> - Each stream record appears exactly once in the stream.
> - For each item that is modified in a DynamoDB table, the stream records appear in the same sequence as the actual modifications to the item.

This will likely be related to your application, ensure that you're not using multiple writes where you think there might be a single.

Also check your [CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/logging-using-cloudtrail.html) to see whether there are multiple API calls that you can see. I would imagine if you're using global tables there's a possibility of seeing a secondary api call as the contents of the item would be modified by the DynamoDB service.

Comment: The changes I made was via dynamodb console not my application. And there is only 1 million second different between these two events.

Comment: I do have global table enabled but I only added one region `ap-southeast-1`.

Comment: 1 millisecond would tend to indicate that there is an API action happening from AWS. When data is written to a global table, AWS add additional columns after so possibly that. Can you see a second putitem event in CloudTrail? And does this happen when you manually add an item via the console?